# How to get values between -1 to 1 like Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") does, on Swipe on mobile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Iam new to Unity, I am trying to make a super hexagon game replica, but I'm confused with the Input in unity. I used Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") for keyboard and it does returns a value to I just used it to rotate around the player object around middle object using transform.RotateAround(). But when I'm trying to get it on mobile device, I made up a script to identify whether it's SWIPE LEFT or SWIPE RIGHT. That does work. But I don't know how to return values based on swipe from -1 to 1. So that I could use the values,  Could someone help. I also add up my script here

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {


    public GameManager gameManager;

    public SwipeController swipe;

    public float moveSpeed = 600f;

    float movement = 0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        this.movement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.forward, this.movement * Time.fixedDeltaTime * -moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

Also My Swipe Script here

```
public class SwipeController : MonoBehaviour
{
private bool tap, swipeLeft, swipeRight, swipeUp, swipeDown;
private bool isDragging;
private Vector2 startTouch, swipeDelta;

private void Update()
{
    tap = swipeLeft = swipeRight = swipeUp = swipeDown = false;

    //stand Alone Inputs

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        isDragging = true;
        tap = true;
        startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
    } else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
        isDragging = false;
        Reset();
    }


    //MOBILE INPUTS

    if (Input.touches.Length > 0 )
    {
        if(Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            tap = true;
            isDragging = true;
            startTouch = Input.touches[0].position;
        } else if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended || Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
        {
            isDragging = false;
            Reset();
        }
    }

    //Distance calcs

    if (isDragging)
    {
        if(Input.touches.Length > 0)
        {
            swipeDelta = Input.touches[0].position - startTouch;
        } else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            swipeDelta = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - startTouch;
        }

        //DEAD ZONE?

    if (swipeDelta.magnitude > 100)
        {
            float x = swipeDelta.x;
            float y = swipeDelta.y;

            if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
            {
                //left or right
                if (x < 0)
                {
                    swipeLeft = true;
                } else
                {
                    swipeRight = true;
                }
            } else
            {
                // top or bottom
                if (y < 0 )
                {
                    swipeDown = true;
                } else
                {
                    swipeUp = true;
                }
            }

            Reset();
        }
    }
}

private void Reset()
{
    startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
}

public Vector2 SwipeDelta { get { return swipeDelta; } }
public bool SwipeLeft { get { return swipeLeft; } }
public bool SwipeRight { get { return swipeRight; } }
public bool SwipeUp { get { return swipeUp; } }
public bool SwipeDown { get { return swipeDown; } }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this :

```
private float RemapFloat(float input, Vector2 refRange, Vector2 targetRange)
{
   // map the input relative to the reference space
   float normal = Mathf.InverseLerp(refRange.x, refRange.y, input);
   // map the result to the target reference space
   float outputValue = Mathf.Lerp(targetRange.x, targetRange.y, normal);
   return outputValue;
}
```

This makes use of :

- InverseLerp : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.InverseLerp.html
- Lerp : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html

You can then call it like that, assuming that the "swipe value" you wish to use is the swipe distance :

```
// the mininum and maximum swipe distance range, could be based on your viewport size
Vector2 swipeValueRange = new Vector2(-swipeDistanceRange, swipeDistanceRange); 
// this is the range of values you wish to use
Vector2 targetRange = new Vector2(-1f, 1f); 
// the swipe value you wish to remap
float swipeValue = currentSwipeValue;

RemapFloat(swipeValue, swipeValueRange, targetRange);
```

Comment: could you find the code attached and point out the thing Im missing for the movement variable..

Comment: this always returns 0... provided with -200, 200 for swipeDistanceRange, currentSwipeValue as the touch position delta. Am i missing soething?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mathf.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.MoveTowards.html) to simulate a value from -1 to 1

Pseudo code:

```
float t;

if(SWIPE LEFT)
{
    t = Mathf.MoveTowards(t, -1, STEP);
}
else if(SWIPE RIGHT)
{
    t = Mathf.MoveTowards(t, 1, STEP);
}
else
{
    t = Mathf.MoveTowards(t, 0, STEP);
}
```

Comment: I couldnt understand the values to be passed, could you please elaborate

Comment: If you are swiping left, move `t` towards -1, if swiping right move t towards 1, and if no swipe, move t towards 0. The `STEP` controls the speed of reaction.